# Backbone: restore focus after rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, focus

I've got a little problem here:

In my Backbone.js app I save changes in a content editable on blur. This means, that when pressing the tab key the whole view is re-rendered and I loose the focus on the next element. How can I restore this?

Comment: Consider disabling the re-render upon blur

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain a property, either in the view (as a plain attribute, as in the example below) or model, to store the currently focused element. Whenever focus changes, update the property.

After re-rendering stuff, set the focus to the element manually.

Here is a minimal code:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#formElement'),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    }

    events: {
        'focus input': "updateFocus"
    },

    updateFocus: function(event) {
        this.focusedElem = $(event.target);
    },

    render: function() {
        // After rendering is complete
        this.focusedElem.focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a dedicated ViewModel and View for every input. It has a special readValue/writeValue methods which update element instead of recreating it. It looks this way:

```
var TextInput = Backbone.Model.extend({ // abstract
    defaults: {
        value: '', // text
        visible: true, // determines if input element is visible
        readonly: false, // determines if input element is read only 
        enabled: true, // determines if input element is enabled
        delay: 750 // view/model sync latency
    }
});

var TextInputView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#text-input').html()),
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.model.bind('change:visible', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('change:readonly', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('change:enabled', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('change:value', this.readValue, this);
    },
    events: {
        'change input': 'writeValue',
        'keyup input': 'writeValue'
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model))
            .find('input')
                .prop({
                    readonly: this.model.get('readonly'),
                    disabled: !this.model.get('enabled')
                })
                .toggleClass('hidden', !this.model.get('visible'));

        this.readValue();
        return this;
    },
    changeTimer: null,
    writeValue: function () {
        if (this.changeTimer)
            clearTimeout(this.changeTimer);

        var that = this;
        this.changeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            that.model.set({ value: that.$('input').val() });
        }, this.model.get('delay'));
    },
    readValue: function () {
        if (this.$('input').val() != this.model.get('value'))
            this.$('input').val(this.model.get('value'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I wanted it to go to the "next" element after rendering. Also, you can't remember an element in JQuery that gets removed from the DOM. So I record the name of the input instead of the input itself. Combining the previous answers you can do something similar to below. Remember I have some assumptions in there, like names on the inputs and that I search within the fieldset.

```
    getNextInputForName = function(desiredName) {
      var desiredElement = false;
        var foundElement;
        $("fieldset input").each(function(index) {
          if (desiredElement) {
              foundElement = $(this);
                return false;
            }
            if ($(this).attr("name") === desiredName) {
                desiredElement = true;
            }
        });
        return foundElement;
    }

    var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $('#formElement'),

      initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
      }

      events: {
        'focus input': "updateFocus"
      },

      updateFocus: function(event) {
        this.focusedElem = $(event.target).attr("name");
      },

      render: function() {
        // After rendering is complete
        if( this.focusedElem ) {
          getNextInputForName(this.focusedElem).focus();
        }
      }
    });
```